# Solving $(-\log x)^2$

Tags: logarithms

I find this property of logarithms quite confusing.

$$(-\log x)^2 = (\log x)^2$$

Can also be

$$(-\log x)^2 = \Big(\log \big(\tfrac{1}{x}\big)\Big)^2$$

Which one is correct?

Comment: Both are correct. Why is that confusing?

Comment: _Both_ are correct. It all stems from the identity $-1\cdot-1=1$.

Comment: @Jeppe oh okay  then, I got confused since I thought one of them had to be wrong to match the answer given in my TB. Thanks

Comment: @ParclyTaxel thank you for helping

Comment: What are you *solving*?

Comment: I was solving integrals with logarithms in them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct.

The first one is not a property of logarithms, it's a property of squares. (-a)²=a² for all a.

The second one follows from the first because 
log(1/x) = log(x⁻¹) = -log(x)